# Need oracle query to consolidate multiple rows into one with a column for each

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the following data set:

```
SELECT * FROM assets;    

AA_ASSET_ID ASSET_ID ASSET_NAME CLASS_ID CLASS_NAME
1023        1023     Head tip   4        Accessory
1023        1056     Sorter     2        Equipment
1023        1557     Workcell   1        Lab System
```

I'd like a query that can output it to one row per aa_asset_id:

```
ID    Lab_System Equipment Accessory
1023  Workcell   Sorter    Head tip
```

I've tinkered with PIVOT but can't quite get this to work. Is there a way to get this to output?

Comment: It's Oracle 12c

Comment: Are there only 3 CLASS_NAMEs?

Comment: This can be done with PIVOT, but there are a few questions you need to consider (and then answer here, so we can help). (1) Do you care about the other data in the table, like ASSET_ID and CLASS_ID?  (2) Are all the class names **known beforehand** (without peeking at the data IN THE TABLE)? (3) Are the column names written in that exact case (initial cap, lower case for the rest of the word) part of your requirement?

Comment: There can be more than 3 but for my particular use case I'm only interested in these 3.

Comment: The class names are constant and known. They are in a related table but they're not going to change. I know that 1,2,4 are what I'm interested in. Yes the class names are in that exact case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select
  aa_asset_id ID,
  max(case class_name when 'Lab System' then asset_name end) Lab_System,
  max(case class_name when 'Equipment' then asset_name end) Equipment,
  max(case class_name when 'Accessory' then asset_name end) Accessory
from assets
group by aa_asset_id
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/921912/1).
Results:

```
ID      LAB_SYSTEM  EQUIPMENT   ACCESSORY
1023    Workcell    Sorter      Head tip
```

Comment: This one seems to be doing what I need.Thank so much to all.

Answer (score 1):

With the PIVOT operator, you can do it like this:  (note - the WITH clause is not part of the solution; I only use it because I don't have your actual table. Remove it when you test on an actual table)

```
with
  assets (aa_asset_id, asset_id, asset_name, class_id, class_name) as (
    select 1023, 1023, 'Head tip', 4, 'Accessory'  from dual union all
    select 1023, 1056, 'Sorter'  , 2, 'Equipment'  from dual union all
    select 1023, 1557, 'Workcell', 1, 'Lab System' from dual
  )
select *
from   (select aa_asset_id, asset_name, class_name from assets)
pivot  (max(asset_name) for class_name in ('Lab System' as "Lab System",
                                           'Equipment'  as "Equipment" ,
                                           'Accessory'  as "Accessory" ))
;

AA_ASSET_ID Lab System Equipment Accessory
----------- ---------- --------  ---------
       1023 Workcell   Sorter    Head tip
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT aa_asset_id, asset_name, class_name
      FROM   assets
      )
PIVOT (
       MAX(asset_name) FOR (class_name) IN (
                                            'Lab System' as "Lab System", 
                                            'Equipment' as Equipment, 
                                            'Accessory' as Accessory )
      )
```

or `PIVOT XML`, in order to have dynamic column names vs. hard coding them.

Maybe something like

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT aa_asset_id, asset_name, class_name
      FROM   assets
     )
PIVOT XML (
           MAX(asset_name) FOR (class_name) IN (SELECT DISTINCT class_name FROM assets)
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the opportunity to use the [`MODEL`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/sqlmodel.htm) clause:

```
select
  id, Lab_System, Equipment, Accessory
from assets
model
  return updated rows
  partition by (AA_ASSET_ID id)
  dimension by (CLASS_NAME)
  measures (
    asset_name,
    cast('' as varchar2(8)) Accessory,
    cast('' as varchar2(8)) Equipment,
    cast('' as varchar2(8)) LAB_SYSTEM
  ) rules (
    Accessory['PIVOT'] = asset_name['Accessory'],
    Equipment['PIVOT'] = asset_name['Equipment'],
    LAB_SYSTEM['PIVOT'] = asset_name['Lab System']
  );
```

**Output:**

```
|  ID  | LAB_SYSTEM | EQUIPMENT | ACCESSORY |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 1024 | Foo        | (null)    | Bar       |
| 1023 | Workcell   | Sorter    | Head tip  |
```

Demo on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e53ae/3).